# Apache camel and kafka integration

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka

I was trying to test camel integration with kafka as explained [here](https://github.com/ipolyzos/camel-kafka/wiki)

Following is my code

```
public class KafkaTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("kafka:test?zkConnect=localhost:2181&metadataBrokerList=localhost:9092")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
                    }
                })
                .end();
            }
        });

        context.start();
        while (true) {

        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[kafka:test?zkConnect=localhost:2181&amp;... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: kafka://test?amp%3BmetadataBrokerList=localhost%3A9092&zkConnect=localhost%3A2181 due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: kafka://test?amp%3BmetadataBrokerList=localhost%3A9092&zkConnect=localhost%3A2181 due to: There are 2 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. 

Unknown parameters=[{metadataBrokerList=localhost:9092, zkConnect=localhost:2181}]
```

Please suggest what could be missing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct parameter names named in the **[official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/kafka)**.

```
from("kafka:localhost:9092?topic=test&zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181")
```

The version you are refering to, described in the wiki at github, was contributed to Apache and changed somewhat since.

Comment: There are 2 camel-kafka components floating around out there.
https://github.com/Giwi/camel-kafka  => 3 years old.  Uses the format the OP was using.
https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-kafka => CURRENT  Uses the parameters represented in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use endpoint class ?

something like:

```
 public static KafkaEndpoint endpoint(String host, String port, String topic, String offset, String groupId) {
        String endpointUri = "kafka://" + host + ":" + port;
        KafkaEndpoint endpoint = new DefaultCamelContext().getEndpoint(endpointUri, KafkaEndpoint.class);
        endpoint.getConfiguration().setTopic(topic);
        endpoint.getConfiguration().setKeyDeserializer("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        endpoint.getConfiguration().setValueDeserializer("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        endpoint.getConfiguration().setAutoOffsetReset(offset);
        endpoint.getConfiguration().setGroupId(groupId);
        return endpoint;
    }

PollingConsumer consumer = endpoint.createPollingConsumer();
```

or

```
new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from(endpoint)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
                    }
                })
                .end();
            }
        }
```